# VIM - coc.vim: no such file or directory

Tags: git, vim, vim-plugin

i've been using vim on git bash, i created a directory `~/.vim/vimrc`  to configure it. So, i've installed **coc.vim** and when i try run `:CocList`  i get:

`[coc.nvim] Error on "CocList lists": ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '\c\Users\MyUser\.config\coc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the other plugins recognised? If using Windows (since you are using Git Bash), I believe the configuration file should be in `~/_vimrc`

Comment: hey, I have the same issue but I do not get your answer. Could you please elaborate? I am missing the 'I believe the configuration file should be in ~/_vimrc' part, what does this mean?

Comment: Hey, I think I made a mistake in my previous answer. I was transitioning from Git Bash to Windows Terminal, and the location of the vimrc file changes. If you run `:version` inside of VIM you can see where it should be (_vimrc for windows terminal). In any case, I don't believe this answers the question regarding coc.vim.